# Oil viscosity 0w30 vs 5w30

Tags: oil, oil-viscosity

There a a lot of articles about viscosity, but I cant find clearly, do I lose anything when I use 0w30 instead of 5w30?

In my climate winter temperatures usually doesn't fall below -20 degrees celsius, but it is possibility to have few nights at -26 or -27 degrees. At summer temperatures can get as high as +35 - +37degrees celsius.

For a car that does about 10000 kilometers per year I change oil once a year. So I am wondering is it OK to put 0w30 oil instead of 5w30? Or should I put 5w30? Oil price does not make difference to me.

I am sure a car will benefit from 0w30 oil at winter times, but how about this oil in summer time? When checking temperature ranges for different oil viscosities it seems it only differs at the bottom temperature -30 degrees for 0w30 and -25 degrees for 5w30. And the top temperature is the same. But in some articles it says one is thicker than another.

Comment: What does your owners manual say?  I'd generally go with what they recommend especially if you have a warranty in effect.

Comment: Owners manual says 0w30 5w30 0w40 5w40. So all of them are recommended. And for example 0w30 is only 50cent/litre more expensive than 5w30 it does not make any difference. So if 0w30 is only better or equal and no downsides compared to 5w30 I would like to go with 0w30. But if it has its' downsides... That is why I asked this question

Comment: My guess is that those different weights of oil have different temperature ranges associated with them.  If so, then use the oil weight that fits the temperate range that you typically operate in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of using 0w30 over 5w30 is easier subzero temperature starting, better oil flow, and lower starter loads. The difference in low temperature ratings may be a few degrees between 0w30 and 5w30 but you'll know by hearing the engine turnover in subzero temperatures. I would presume 0w30 will let the starter run a little easier and not load the battery compared to 5w30. As far 30 in both multi viscosity oils, they're the same otherwise there'd be a lot of complaints. At your low temperatures, I wouldn't hesitate to switch to 0w30 oil. Engines are manufactured with tighter tolerances compared to yesteryears engines due to using CNC machining for consistent precision machining processes. A lower viscosity oil like 5w in a multi viscosity oil flows better in tighter engines and contributes to fuel mileage compared to older engines using 10w30. For whatever reason, I'm using 5w30 synthetic oil and have zero oil consumption issues and extending oil changes with 115k miles on an '03 vehicle with a 3.0L V6 engine.